# error with strcpy and strcmp and the argument of the printf and scanf

Tags: c

```
typedef struct staff {

int id, salary;
char name[30], position[30];
}staff;

void modifyStaff() {
char ans, cont, name[25], position[20];
int i = 0, pCount, modiCount = 0, found, id[20];
int salary[20];
staff P[20];
FILE*fp;
fp = fopen("staff.dat", "rb");
while (fread(&P[i], sizeof(staff), 1, fp))
    i++;
pCount = i;
fclose(fp);
do {
    printf("\nEnter ID of the Staff to be modified : ");

    rewind(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &id);
    found = 0;

    printf("\nID    NAME   POSITION    SALARY \n");
    printf("============   ===========    ======= \n");
    for (i = 0; i < pCount; i++) {
        if (id == P[i].id == 0) {
            found = 1;
            printf("%-18d %-10s %-10s %-10d \n",
                P[i].id, P[i].name, P[i].position, P[i].salary);
            printf("\n Updated Name:");

            scanf("%[^\n]", &name);
            printf("\n Updated Position:");

            scanf("%[^\n]", &position);
            printf("\n Updated salary:");

            scanf("%d", &salary);
            printf("Confirm to Modify (Y=yes)? ");

            scanf("%c", &ans);
            if (toupper(ans) == 'Y') {
                P[i].id = id;
                strcpy(P[i].name, name);
                strcpy(P[i].position, position);
                P[i].salary=salary;
                modiCount++;
            }
            printf("Updated Staff Records:\n");
            printf("\nID NAME POSITION SALARY\n");
            printf("========  ========= =========== ========\n");
            printf("%-18d %-10s %-10s %-10d", P[i].id, P[i].name, P[i].position, P[i].salary);
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        printf("NO record founded with this ID");
    printf("Any more record to modify?(Y=yes)?");

    scanf("%c", &cont);
} while (toupper(cont) == 'Y');
fp = fopen("staff.dat", "wb");
for (i = 0; i < pCount; i++)
    fwrite(&P[i], sizeof(staff), 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
printf("\n\t%d Record(s) modified.\n\n", modiCount);
```

}

it will change the name and the position but for the salary it will show access of violation. i want to change the salary and store the new one.but it cannot store the new one the compiler execute until the line comfirm to modify ? and then stop execute. Staff P represent all of the P[i] in the modify function

Comment: **1)** The strcpy() and strncpy() functions return a pointer to the destination string dest. **2)** The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than,  to  match,
       or be greater than s2.

Comment: which mean i have to change the strcmp and strcpy?

Comment: Yes, you should change them.

Comment: There is a lot of code in your EDIT part, but there is no related code which actually can be checked. How do you declare your struct for example. What means this `P[i].id, P[i].name, P[i].position, P[i].salary);` ? You should put a code which we can verify it and which we can compile it.

Comment: typedef struct staff {

 int id, salary;
 char name[30], position[30];

}staff

Comment: the P[i].id is represent the id inside the struct

Comment: I cannot help you, if you do not help your self. Where do you declare `P`? Please do not do that in comments. Use edit option and ad this information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my Comments:

- The `strcpy()` and `strncpy()` functions return a pointer to the destination string dest.
- The `strcmp()` and `strncmp()` functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

The following program should explain the use of both Functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 256
struct pers{
    char dest[SIZE];
};

int main ( void ){

    struct pers data;
    const char *src = "Hello";

    if ( ( strlen( src ) + 1) <  SIZE ){
        strcpy( data.dest, src );
    }else{
        printf("The SRC is bigger then DEST\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( strcmp( data.dest, src ) == 0 ){
        printf("SRC and DEST are equal:\n\n");
        printf("\tSRC  = %s\n", src);
        printf("\tDEST = %s\n", data.dest);
    }else{
        printf("SRC and DEST are  NOT equal\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SRC and DEST are equal:

    SRC  = Hello
    DEST = Hello
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i still don't understand where the mistake

Comment: For comparison you need `strcmp` and when you need to copy you need `strcpy`. That being said, you are using `strcpy` when you need `strcmp` and you are using `strcmp` there where you need `strcpy` .

Comment: ohhh...i see ..thank you very much

Comment: @Hshdhx I made some extra check, please see my Updated Code.

Comment: i change my code...strcmp to strcpy...it work for name and position but for salary the error say access of violation.

Comment: @Hshdhx You could start with editing your Question with the code which actually does not work to see where the problem is.

Comment: i have edited the code